# About normal derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Let $w:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega$ is an open, bounded, connected set, $w \in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline\Omega)$ and $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ such that $w(x_0)=0$. Is there anyway to proove that the normal derivative $\partial w_n(x_0)$ is non-negative?

Answer (score 1):

If $w$ satisfied some PDE in which we had a maximum principle, then $u$ would obtain its maximum on the boundary, if we assume $w\le 0,w\ne 0$ then $w$ would be increasing up to the boundary and the normal derivative would be non negative. Basically we need something to impose that $w$ increases up to the boundary, the given assumptions are not enough.

Comment: But if $x_0$ is the maximum of $w$, when we calculate $\partial w_n(x_0)$ the result shouldn't be $0$? $\nabla w(x_0)$ should be a vector which points to the greatest increase of $w$. But since $x_0$ is a maximum point, $\nabla w(x_0)=0$ which implies $\partial w_n(x_0)=0$. And would you explain in a few words why if a function increases up to the boundary, it's normal derivative is non negative?

Comment: The theory of maxima and mimina, I.e. finding a critical point is a "one way" idea, I.e. if $\nabla w(x_0)=0$, then $x_0$ is a critical point, which may be a maximum or minimum, but it does not go the other way, for example take $w=x^2+y^2-1$ on the open unit disk, this attains its maximum on the boundary, but the gradient is non zero here, and so there is no critical point on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Not without additional assumptions on $w$. If $w$ is a function as in your assumptions and $\partial_n w(x_0) > 0$, then $u = -w$ will also satisfy the assumptions but $\partial_n u(x_0) < 0$.

Comment: What about if $w\leq0$ on $\Omega$?